# Find tangent from other two trig ratios

Tags: trigonometry

I understand the six trig ratios, and know that tangent= opposite/adjacent. I feel like, on a website, I've seen people use either cosine/sine or sine/cosine (can't remember which) to find the tangent.

Is one of these two (cos/sin or sin/cos) valid/does it work?

Comment: Have you read the [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent) articles?

Comment: I looked, but I don't think i found what I was looking for.

Comment: $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and you can deduce it from your "six trigo ratios"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of tangent

$$\tan{x} = \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}$$

is what they are referring to.

Similarly, the other trigonometric ratios are defined as follows
$$\cot{x} = \frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}} \\ \sec{x} = \frac{1}{\cos{x}} \\ \csc{x} = \frac{1}{\sin{x}}$$

Comment: I thought so - I was not quite sure as to if it was correct.

Comment: Also $\cot x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$

Comment: True, true. Haha.